# zsh path "no such file or directory" where do I unset it?

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I just noticed that my `$PATH` has an invalid location:

`\> $PATH

zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: ...`

I use prezto and according to the docs the config files are sourced in this order:

1. /etc/zshenv
2. ~/.zshenv
3. /etc/zprofile
4. ~/.zprofile
5. /etc/zshrc
6. ~/.zshrc
7. ~/.zpreztorc
8. /etc/zlogin
9. ~/.zlogin
10. ~/.zlogout
11. /etc/zlogout

I checked the whole list and I can't find anything that would come before `/usr/bin`

Any suggestion on how I could go about finding what is triggering the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is nothing wrong with your `PATH`. If you want to see the content of `PATH` use `echo`:

```
% echo $PATH
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

`PATH` is a colon separated list of directories to search for commands. Essentially, zsh will try the name of your command with each path and execute the first find (`/usr/sbin/foo`, `/usr/bin/foo`, etc.). If any of the listed directories does not exist, there will be no error message, zsh will simply not find a binary there and try the next one.

The issue in your case is triggered by trying to execute `$PATH`. Before executing a command line, zsh - among other things - replaces all variables with their content, this is called *Parameter Expansion* (so `man 1 zshexpn` for more information on that).

So, when you just write `$PATH`, zsh replaces it with `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:...` and interpretes it as one long path. That is, `:` is not taken as separator but as part of the directory names. Any you are getting the same error message you would get with any other non-existent directory:

```
% ls /some/path
dir1 dir2
% /some/path/nothere/notthere
zsh: no such file or directory: /some/path/nothere/notthere
```

Comment: Although I have little hope of getting an answer, but here it is: Why the downvote? I am reasonably (read: very) sure that I correctly diagnosed and answered the question. If there is a factual error or some other problem with the answer, I would like to know what it is, so that I learn something and/or improve the answer.